# How to reset the terminal properties and preferences?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I fooled around with the colors and stuff, in the terminal, and now want to go back to the maroon and white default config of the the terminal. What files do I have to delete?

Comment: Deleting `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal` or using `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal` as others suggested works, but you need to relog to see changes.

Comment: What does "**relog**" mean? I mean, how can I **relog**?

Comment: @NaveNobel I think he means to say a relogin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In terminal click on the  'Edit' menu then 'Profile Preferences'. It will pop up the 'Editing Profile' Window. to reset the color make sure that you have selected the check box named 'Use colors from system theme' in the 'Colors' tab.[image]

Comment: I have, but I see a white BG only.

Comment: I also tried creating a new profile, but that didnt help. Things like changing the Cursor shape, produced instant changes in the terminal. but changing the colors, unfortunately did not.

Comment: Is this the same for all user account including root?.. or just for your account?

Comment: Which is the theme you are using ?

Comment: It depends on the theme you are using. if you select the default theme 'Ambiance' and follow the above you will get a terminal with maroon and white colors. Or if you want to keep your current theme then you need edit the terminal profile to get the desired output.

Comment: yes, i was on a different theme. I used New Wave, thats why the default colors were different from the expected colors. I switched to Ambiance, and now it works. Kind of strange though.

Comment: FWIW, for me at least, changing the built-in scheme to (for exmample) Linux console and then changing it back to Custom screwed up how the terminal displayed vim files (it didn't use my specified color scheme) _even if I selected "Use colors from system theme"_. I had to use `rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal` from the comment on the original post to get vim colors looking normal again.

Answer (score 28):

Try     `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal`

Comment: thx this worx..

Comment: This is also useful (along with other command line options) if you disabled menu access in the terminal settings by accident (and can't access the menu).

Comment: Very useful -- especially if gnome-terminal is no longer working through SSH through -X. (Like messing up a profile with a custom theme).

Comment: How do I undo this?

Comment: nope. did not work

Answer (score 22):

### Ubuntu 16.04

This simple command works in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

---

**Reset only the default profile**

However, if you want to reset only the default profile, which uses UUID `b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9` [by default](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/tree/src/org.gnome.Terminal.gschema.xml), you can use

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/
```

---

<sup>Note: This method should work in Ubuntu 15.04, 15.10 and may work in 14.04 too! But I haven't tested on those versions</sup>

Comment: `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/` does the trickc on ubuntu 16

Comment: @prayagupd Yes. that too works. but it can clear all profiles preference. and it was in my answer

Comment: Also worked on Debian 9.4.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do a complete reset of the Gnome Terminal settings, you can remove the `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal` directory which contains them. I would close all terminal windows on your desktop. Then switch away from the GUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login on the console.

You should probably backup the directory first, with something like:

```
cp -a ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal ~/terminal-settings.bak
```

Then remove it:

```
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal
```

Now, you can switch back to the GUI with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and launch the terminal. It should be reset to system default settings.

Comment: :D wow, thanks Sir! But I am afraid, that did not work! And I havent changed the color-schemes, so its not that the settings are default, but the colors are new.

Comment: `cp: cannot stat '/home/prayagupd/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal': No such file or directory`

Comment: None of this is working for me :(

Answer (score 6):

In order to reset terminal , one must understand first what part you want to reset exactly - do you want to reset graphical looks ? do you want to reset the shell ?

First of all, default terminal in Ubuntu is `gnome-terminal` so for 99% of new users, I assume you're using `gnome-terminal`. Advanced users, who use something other than `gnome-terminal` will have to refer to manuals of their respective terminal emulators.

#### Resetting  gnome-terminal GUI preferences to default

In order to reset `gnome-terminal` it is sufficient to do  this:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

Alternatively, you could use GUI tool called `dconf-editor`.

**NOTE**: Multiple answers here suggest `gconftool-2`.   However, `GConf`

> . . .was deprecated as part of the GNOME 3 transition. Migration to its replacement, GSettings and dconf, is ongoing ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GConf))

#### Resetting shell

It is a frequent question by users that they have something with their shell, and now the text in terminal looks different or they see an error. Simple, quick and dirty way is to get rid of old `~/.bashrc` file and replace it with default one, stored in `/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc`
You can do so via terminal or via GUI - doesn't matter. Via terminal, you'd do `cat /usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc > ~/.bashrc` and via GUI - delete old file, copy `/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc` from file manager to your home folder and rename as `.bashrc`

#### Gnome Terminal doesn't open

So you have changed some setting and now `gnome-terminal` doesn't work. Great, what now ? Luckly, there's couple of ways to get around this.

One, start `xterm`.  By default, Ubuntu comes with two terminal emulators. `xterm` is the original terminal emulator for X11 GUI and has been around since long ago, when dinosaurs of Unix systems roamed the earth.  You can use it to call the `dconf` command mentioned above, as well as reset your `~/.bashrc` config file.

Another approach, would be use `dconf-editor` tool, again mentioned above. If you don't have it installed - use Software Center to get it.

Finally, you can always purge and reinstall the terminal. Purging the gnome-terminal means any config files associated with it will be removed and it will be installed from scratch. The command to do so is `sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-terminal` and then `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`. This can be done via `xterm` or TTY  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-6]</kbd>)

#### I did something to my prompt , I want it to look like user@hostname:~$ again.

Here's the thing: the prompt has two static parts `username@hostname:` and `$`. The one in the middle, `~`, means your current working directory. Just like in file manager, when you jump to different directories, the terminal will display the directory in which you're working right now. So for example:

```
xieerqi@eagle:~$ cd /etc
xieerqi@eagle:/etc$ cd /home/$USER/Desktop
xieerqi@eagle:~/Desktop$
```

If you want to see `~` again, all you have to do is jump back to your home directory:

```
xieerqi@eagle:~/Desktop$ cd
xieerqi@eagle:~$
```

If you want to permanently get rid of the directory information in your prompt, you should edit your `~/.bashrc` file. Add this line:

```
PS1="\u@\h:$"
```

Save the file and run source ~/.bashrc . Now you have a static prompt. Big problem is that you won't see where you are at the moment, so you will have to rely on pwd command for that and be careful not to delete valuable files ( so you have been warned :)

You can also use `bash --posix` which will display this type of prompt:

```
$ bash --posix
bash-4.3$
```

#### I don't want to deal with this, just give me working terminal

That's fairly easy: install some other terminal emulator. Oh, and there's [plenty to choose from](http://www.tuxarena.com/intro/ref_term.php).  Personally, I'd recommend `terminator`, `guake` or `sakura`

Answer (score 2):

When you are in **Terminal**, go to **Edit** > **Profile preferences**, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to open the **Editing Profile** dialog. After make sure to select everything as below images.

Also, make sure that the value of `PS1` in `~/.bashrc` file is:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

[image: general]

[image: title and command]

[image: colors]

[image: background]

[image: scrolling]

[image: compatibility]

Answer (score 0):

I played with it which resulted in removing all colors.. and kept me with monochrome..No difference between file and directories.

Try either of this:

```
ls --color=auto  
ls --color=tty
```

Reference:  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-turn-on-or-off-colors-in-bash/

Might help someone...