# How to recover from terminal custom setup

Tags: gnome-terminal

I installed ubuntu 12.04 and I added "Terminal" to the launcher bar, the default size of the terminal is a bit small, after some googling here is how I made the disaster change:

1. At HUD menu, type "preference" and I see the option of `Edit > preference`, this is as I expected
2. After I clicked the option, I forget the exact steps, but somehow I came to some configuration panel and there is a checkbox for terminal "custom" and I checked it
3. now an input box is enabled and I type `gnome-terminal --geometry 160x50`

Now the problem comes, whenever I click the terminal button at the launcher bar, new terminal windows pops up endlessly from everywhere, I cannot do anything any more except logout or shutdown.

The weird thing is, after I come back, I cannot get that `Edit > preference` any more when I type "preference" in HUD, I tried "Edit", "preference".

To be clear, I still can use the computer as long as I do not click that terminal button, but I really want to use terminal to run commands.

Help is appreciated greatly!

Update -

OK, figured out.

Go to /home/jibin/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default and open that xml file, I can see the options I changed at the GUI, remove them and terminal runs good.

The preference HUD is back also, it is actually Profile Preference and it is only available when terminal is open.

Continue my ubuntu-ing...

Comment: See the second answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14487/how-to-reset-the-terminal-properties-and-preferences

Comment: Since the order answers are shown may change, [here's a direct link to that answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/14505/22949).