# gnome-terminal creates a space after each accentuated letter

Tags: gnome-terminal, 16.10, encoding

This is reproduced in Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 and 16.10, when I type "é" in shell or any editor (vi, nano, ...), ubuntu prints "é ".

Could someone explain me how to get rid of this ?

UPDATE :

- When I say I "reproduce" on different versions of Ubuntu, it's only by opening a terminal on my desktop Ubuntu 16.10, so I guess only this one has the problem.
- The font is the default font, if I change the font, it doesn't resolve this problem

Comment: Try to switch to some other font and check if the problem is still present.

Comment: What language, what font, what keyboard layout?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Ok, I tried, see my update

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. Please describe in detail what keyboard layout you are using and how you are entering the character.

Comment: it doesn't look related to the input method because apt logs will write for example : "fichiers et ré pertoires dé jà  installé s". In the upper right menu, I've tried to switch to "En", and then when I display french man pages with accents, the problem is still there.

Comment: Please show the output of `env | grep '^\(LANG\|LC_\)'`.

Comment: When I type "locale", everything is set to "fr_FR.UTF-8" except LANGUAGE which is "fr_FR". Your command displays "LANG" and "LANGUAGE".

Comment: I narrowed the problem a bit : it doesn't happen with xterm or konsole, only with gnome-terminal. Is there a way to reset gnome-terminal settings to default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I get it.

Since it was related to gnome-terminal only, I tried to reset all gnome-terminal settings.

I passed this command and my gnome terminal was cured :

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

source : [How to reset the terminal properties and preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14487/how-to-reset-the-terminal-properties-and-preferences)

*Note* : the following command did no error but did not work for my problem :

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal
```