# Ubuntu Bionic terminal keeps opening tmux as shell

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Sometime last week while bored I was searching through the many apps and setting of my ubuntu system. I found a **GUI** option to set tmux (maybe tmx) as the default terminal, from what I remember? It turns out that tabs do not autofill, and it is missing many features that make it next to unusable for me. But I cannot find this option anywhere anymore to change it back. I have tried commandline options online for changing default terminal, but nothing is working. Opening xterm also just shows tmx.

Help is appreciated, because tab actually tabbing is getting on my nerves immensely.

EDIT:

the default terminal is already correct, its the fact that opening gnome-terminal, opens in tmux and is unusable. also tried reseting the settings as in [How to reset the terminal properties and preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14487/how-to-reset-the-terminal-properties-and-preferences) to no avail... Also looked through .bashrc and saw nothing. The preferences show no option for this either or my own system settings that I can find, but not a gnome-terminal specific problem since affects xterm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set default terminal used in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used-in-unity)  - I know it says Unity in the title, but it's a Gnome setting, so it should work even if you're using Ubuntu 17.10 or newer

Comment: added explanation to why its not.

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: Every link in that post, but the default terminal is already correct, its the fact that opening gnome-terminal, opens in tmux and is unusable. also tried reseting the settings as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/14487/how-to-reset-the-terminal-properties-and-preferences to no avail... Also looked through .bashrc and saw nothing. But its not the normal tmux app, it doesnt have the same usage (Edit, i think it is, just different when run on its own). the preferences show no option for this either or my own system settings that I can find.

Comment: Its not being run after opening gnome-terminal, as closing the tmux session closes the terminal..

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: Oh, tmux is a terminal multiplexer! You referred to it as a terminal in some spots so I think I got it confused with Terminator.

Comment: Was the GUI setting "[Run a custom command instead of my shell](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-custom-command.html.en)" in Gnome Terminal? **Edit**: nvm, I just saw you said it affects xterm as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used `chsh` and changed it back to `/bin/bash`, then restarted my computer, and everything is fixed now. Where the GUI option was, will forever be a mystery that haunts me after hours of looking.

Comment: idk how the correct answer gets a downvote. If its the way I wrote it, comment about it then. Its a waste.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset my system"? I'm not sure why this was downvoted btw.